# Buffered Input Stream mark read limit

Tags: java, inputstream

I am learning how to use an InputStream. I was trying to use mark for BufferedInputStream, but when I try to reset I have these exceptions:

```
java.io.IOException: Resetting to invalid mark
```

I think this means that my mark read limit is set wrong. I actually don't know how to set the read limit in mark(). I tried like this:

```
is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
is.mark(is.available());
```

This is also wrong.

```
is.mark(16);
```

This also throws the same exception.
How do I know what read limit I am supposed to set? Since I will be reading different file sizes from the input stream.

Comment: My personal take? Don't use mark - while I'm sure there is one, I have yet to find a good reason for it. Often times it's a sign of poor handling in the first place. I tend to think of a stream as not a stream unless I'm dealing with the most raw form it has. I'd rather have a tight wrapper around it that gets its information, packages it up, and sends that package for processing somewhere in the app.

Comment: @glowcoder Thanks for your comment. As i said earlier, i am new in working with InputStream. I was actually trying to use input stream twice. I thought that this is the way to do it. Setting mark and reset. Do you have other suggestion on how to achive this?

Comment: Mark works like this. Let's say your input stream would end up being `A B C D E`. You process `A B` so far. (Remember, you don't know what's 'downstream' yet.) You mark it. You then read some more, and you get `C D E`. You look at it and say "Wait, I can't process `C D E` in this mode!" for whatever reason. So you say "I really wish I could go back to process `C D E` again... which you can, since you `mark()`ed it. You just `reset()` to put the stream back to where it was when you marked it, and you can read it over again like you would have before.

Comment: So when you say "I want to use the input stream twice" could you clarify what you're trying to do? I'm sure the community can come up with something (code example, or at least guidance) to help you achieve your goals.

Comment: @glowcoder This is the situation. I have an input stream. which first would be used to read by apache POI to get the document attribute. Then the same input stream will be used to be read again and stored the document. The problem is. After apache poi take the input stream, the document is stored but the size is 0. I think this was caused by the input stream had been read before.

Comment: How many bytes is this document attribute?

Comment: @glowcoder actually i dont know how many bytes is the document attribute. But from the apache poi svn respository, i saw that they use this `final byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.available()]` , and then use the `buffer.length()`

Answer (score 7):

`mark` is sometimes useful if you need to inspect a few bytes beyond what you've read to decide what to do next, then you reset back to the mark and call the routine that expects the file pointer to be at the beginning of that logical part of the input. I don't think it is really intended for much else.

If you look at the javadoc for [BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) it says

> The mark operation remembers a point in the input stream and the reset operation causes all the bytes read since the most recent mark operation to be reread before new bytes are taken from the contained input stream.

The key thing to remember here is once you mark a spot in the stream, **if you keep reading beyond the marked length, the mark will no longer be valid**, and the call to reset will fail. So mark is good for specific situations and not much use in other cases.

Comment: thanks for your comment. when you said that 'if you keep reading and the buffer needs to be refilled'. Is that happening because i used BufferedInputStream?

Comment: Yes, however, unbuffered io streams do not support mark and reset.

Answer (score 2):

This will read 5 times from the same BufferedInputStream.

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
   inputStream.mark(inputStream.available()+1);
   // Read from input stream
   Thumbnails.of(inputStream).forceSize(160, 160).toOutputStream(out);
   inputStream.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value you pass to `mark()` is the amount backwards that you will need to reset.  if you need to reset to the beginning of the stream, you will need a buffer as big as the entire stream.  this is probably not a great design as it will not scale well to large streams.  if you need to read the stream twice and you don't know the source of the data (e.g. if it's a file, you could just re-open it), then you should probably copy it to a temp file so you can re-read it at will.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i was planning to reset it to the beginning. But now i think that its not a good idea. When u said i should copy it to temp file, do u mean that i need to store it somewhere in my folder first before using it?

Comment: @NurAini - yes, create a temp file, copy the stream into it, then you can re-read that temp file as many times as you need to.