# FileInputstream and BufferedInputStream work in 4.0.3, but not in 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, file

I have two phones, a galaxy s4 with android 4.2.2 and a galaxy s2 with android 4.0.3. I am opening a torrent file in order to read the info. I got this code :

```
metafile = new Metafile(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(DotTorrentPath)));
```

Metafile is a class from a library. On my g4, I get an internal error from the library which parse the torrent file. `java.io.IOException: Problem parsing bencoded file`. On my g2, everything works fine. I've been browsing the internet for changes about FileInputStream or BufferedInputStream in 4.2, but I didn't find anything.

On both phones, the DotTorrentPath is /mnt/sdcard/Download/thisisatorrent.torrent

The code of the library is

```
private Object parse(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    is.mark(0);
    int readChar = is.read();
    switch (readChar) {
        case 'i':
            return parseInteger(is);
        case 'l':
            return parseList(is);
        case 'd':
            return parseDictionary(is);
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            is.reset();
            return parseByteString(is);
        default:
            throw new IOException("Problem parsing bencoded file");
    }
}
```

On my g2, the `is.read()` returns 100. On my g4, it returns 31. I am using exactly the same file. Any ideas why it is not working on 4.2?

Thanks for the help

Comment: How well does mark() work together with BufferedInputStream? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599172/buffered-input-stream-mark-read-limit

Comment: Have you tried when removing the buffered inputstream?

Comment: Yes, but the fileinputstream is not mark() supported

Comment: Before calling the parse(), the library has this condition if(!is.markSupported()) throw error;

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. That permission was added in Android 4.1 [(see docs)](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Permissions).

Comment: I didn't have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, but it still not working

Comment: The read permission was added in 4.1, but not enforced until 4.4. Quote from your own docs link: *"In Android 4.1 by default all applications still have read access"*, and the [KitKat API](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#BehaviorStorage): *"Your app can not read shared files on the external storage when running on Android 4.4, unless your app has the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission"*.

Comment: Not setting READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE would result in not being able to access the file (FileNotFoundException, permission denied, etc) Since the OP is able to call .read() and pass the char into the switch he obviously has read access.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like an encoding problem to me.  Probably in one phone the file is encoding in UTF-8 (which uses up two bytes), and in the other phone the file is in ANSI (which uses only one byte).

Try checking that the both files have the same encoding...

Also, the documentation [recommends](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html) that you use FileReader to read characters, as opposed to bytes, from a file.

```
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(DotTorrentPath));
```